# Handling Date and DateTime timezones

Tags: django, datetime, timezone

I have an API which has to do with transactions.

Where Parent Transaction ( **PT** ) can have multiple Child Transactions.
Both, in Parent and Child Transaction ( **CT** ) i store the date-time field to UTC.( i use Django's `DateTime(auto_now_add=True` )

But i need to clear some things out so here are my questions:

1. I need to import transactions from a CSV file to my current API, where most of the transactions in the CSV are in local time zone and have only date (YYYY-MM-DD) how should i handle this ?
2. Client selects from Date picker a date ( 2017-12-28 ) how should i search that in my API? cause i don't have a time, and timezone is different.

Answer (score 0):

When you only have year, month, and day, then do not use a `datetime` type.  Use a `date` type instead.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#datefield

Time zones are not applicable when working with date-only values.

Comment: In my case i need to store Date and Time, cause i need the time information, but users will filter by Date.
There is another problem where Transactions can have a custom date entered.
So when storing the Date only, should i store Users Date timezone or Servers date Timezone.

Comment: What time information?  You said in your question that the transactions have only a date in the csv file.